# Foreach Object with one element PHP

Tags: php, object, foreach

I have an object called `$people`. It is filled by my database. This object looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 21
        [fname] => Billy
        [lname] => Boemba
        [email] => email@example.com
        [country] => The Netherlands
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 22
        [fname] => Jill
        [lname] => Jimba
        [email] => email@example.com
        [country] => Austria
    )
```

And my foreach like this:

```
foreach($people as $person){
    // echo some stuff about the person
}
```

All this works, but when I have one record in my database, so `$people` has only one element, I got a error when I try to use `foreach()`:
`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

So how can I use the `foreach()` function with one element in my object?

Comment: Where is `$people` getting initialized?

Comment: check `is_array($people)` before foreach

Comment: The function that creates `$people` should make it an array all the time, not a single object when there is only one person, so that you don't have to check this all the time.

Comment: No, first of all do `var_dump($people)` for that case where you see the error (before the foreach call)

Comment: before this code, and I know it works, but when i remove record in the database, so there is only one record left, the php gives a error as I said

Comment: @user3009553: Stop guessing, start `var_dump()`ing. Proof or didn't happen (you most likely have an error so `$people` is `NULL` or `FALSE`, just try it out)

Comment: or you could do `$people = is_array($people) ? $people : array($people);` before the loop if the function or method returning your data is core code of some framework you are using.. assuming that $people is an object which you should check first ;)

Comment: @Jay: No, the code should either handle the collection (and as this is foreach, it should always be that collection *already*) or the single element. It's not good to introduce such variation checks here and there, instead make functions return the same type as Barmar commented already.

Comment: @hakre assuming the function or method is code you are allowed to modify.

Comment: @hakre really so why are there topics dedicated to existing frameworks such as Laravel, Yii, CodeIgniter etc in which you will not be able to modify core code. If you are then simply you are a cowboy.

Comment: @Jay: All those programs you named are open to changes and ship with source-code and are easily fork-able with upstream support for patches.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach can be run on one element array. I suppose that some part of your script simple doesn't return array when there is only one element and that's why you have problem with foreach

Comment: Foreach can also run on an object, actually *any* object. It's just that `$people` is neither an array nor an object.

Comment: @hakre Only `Iterable` objects surely?

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten the same error when I did not have the proper error checking and I was passing a boolean into the foreach loop:

```
if (!$sth = $this->database->query($query)) {
    print_r($this->database->errorInfo());
}

if(!$record = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    die('record not found');
}else{
    return $record;
}
```

Comment: But I got no error when I fetch the object, but I got an error when I tried to foreach them

Comment: The fetch function will run. It simply returns FALSE if it fails to return the record.

"The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type. In all cases, FALSE is returned on failure." -http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

because the `$people` is an object not an array. use var_dump($people),you will find that the $people is an object. If $people contains more than one object, you will find that the $people is an array when using var_dump($people).

function foreach only work on the array object. So thing goes wrong.

is_array($people) would be a good solution.